# If (X,A) is a CW pair, consisting of a cellcomplex X and a subcomplex A, then $X/A ≃ X ∪ CA$

Tags: algebraic-topology

Textbook explanation. I'm study (self-study) the Hatcher's Algebraic topology.

In his book Example 0.13.

If $(X,A)$ is a CW pair, consisting of a cellcomplex $X$ and a subcomplex $A$, then $X/A ≃ X ∪ CA$, the mapping cone of the
inclusion $A\hookrightarrow X$

Which he said is :For we have $X/A = (X∪CA)/CA ≃ X∪CA$ since CA is a contractible
subcomplex of $X ∪ CA$.

The $CA=(A\times I)/(A\times\{0\})$. I don't know how can get $X/A = (X∪CA)/CA ≃ X∪CA$. Can anyone felp me?

Comment: See proposition 0.17 ${}{}{}$

Comment: But the proposition 0.17 required (X,A) satisfies the homotopy extension property .

Comment: Cw pairs satisfy this. Keyword for googling is “cofibration”